# Check if directory is /Library or /Public

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script which takes a users home directory and cycles through the first level of subdirectories and performs some maintenance on those directories only if it is not the /Library or /Public folder.  The code I have so far does not work as I get an error message saying that the directory name returned by $dir is a directory.  Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

user="short name"
source_root="/Users/"

source_use="$source_root$user"
cd "$source_use"

dirarr=( */ )

echo ${dirarr[@]}

for dir in "${dirarr[@]}"
do 
    if ( "$dir" -ne "/Library" -o "$dir" -ne "/Public")
        then echo $dir.
            # do something
    fi
done
```

Can anyone help me get this working.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script has several problems:

1. You need to use `[ ]` or `[[ ]]` in your `if` statement, not `( )`.  In your example `( )` creates a subshell and tries to run a command `"$dir"`, which is the reason you're getting the error message you see.
2. You're comparing against strings that you won't find - try `"Library/"` and `"Public/"` instead.
3. You probably want `-a` instead of `-o`.
4. `-ne` is used to compare numbers.  You want `!=`.

Here's a corrected version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

user="short name"
source_root="/Users/"

source_use="$source_root$user"
cd "$source_use"

dirarr=( */ )

echo ${dirarr[@]}

for dir in "${dirarr[@]}"
do 
    if [ "$dir" != "Library/" -a "$dir" != "Public/" ]
    then
        echo $dir.
        # do something
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cd $source_root$user

for dir in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d`
do
  if [ $dir = ./Library ] || [ $dir = ./Public ]
  then
    continue
  fi

  (Perform actions)
done
```

Also, bash is backwards. `!=` is string non-equality, `-ne` is integer non-equality. So, change to equals signs, too.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your solution.  I was only trying to find non hidden directories in the users home folder whereas this solution finds all directories.  As I am still learning bash it was useful to see this alternative solution.  Thank you.

Comment: @pdoak - if you're trying to look for non-hidden directories, you should use [`GetFileInfo(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/GetFileInfo.1.html) instead of hardcoding directory names.